# Java cannot create simple 2d boolean array

Tags: java, arrays, exception, multidimensional-array

Running the code:

```
    public static boolean[][] makeright(boolean tf, BufferedImage in){
        boolean[][] ret = new boolean[in.getWidth()][in.getHeight()];
        Arrays.fill(ret, tf);
        return ret;
    }
```

gave me a

```
java.lang.ArrayStoreException: java.lang.Boolean
    at java.util.Arrays.fill(Arrays.java:2697)
    at neuro.helper.makeright(helper.java:35)
    at neuro.helper.main(helper.java:20)
```

exception, line 35 is the line where I create the boolean[][] ret.
Does anybody know what a ArrayStoreException is and how I can prevent it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to using `Arrays.fill()` on a 2 dimensional array instead of a 1 dimensional. You can solve this by looping over the separate (1 dimensional) arrays in your 2D array.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        boolean[][] ret = new boolean[5][5];
        for(boolean[] arr : ret){
            Arrays.fill(arr, true);
        }

        for(boolean[] arr : ret){
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        }
    }
}
```

This will output

```
[true, true, true, true, true]
[true, true, true, true, true]
[true, true, true, true, true]
[true, true, true, true, true]
[true, true, true, true, true]
```

See the [`ArrayStoreException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayStoreException.html):

> Thrown to indicate that an attempt has been made to store the wrong type of object into an array of objects.

And [`Arrays.fill(boolean[] a, boolean val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28boolean%5B%5D,%20boolean%29):

> Assigns the specified boolean value to each element of the specified **array of booleans** .

You can also use the more general [`public static void fill(Object[] a, Object val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20java.lang.Object%29) to pass in an array of boolean values like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean[][] ret = new boolean[5][5];
    boolean[] tofill = new boolean[] { true, true, true, true, true };

    Arrays.fill(ret, tofill);

    for (boolean[] arr : ret) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no version of `Arrays.fill` that accepts a `boolean[][]` as parameter. See the docs [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html).

Or course, as R.J. pointed out in the comments, you can pass a `boolean[][]` as first parameter as long as you pass a `boolean[]` as the second parameter.

Comment: A 2-d array is a 1-d array of 1-d arrays. If you provide a 1-d array as the second argument of the `fill` method, it would work. And that's the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to fill an array of Boolean arrays with single boolean values which will not work. Instead you will have to do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ret.length; i++) {
   Arrays.fill(ret[i], tf);
}
```